# PlayN application in IFrame doesn't have keyboard input

Tags: html, gwt, iframe, playn

I have made my first PlayN app and it works just great until it is embedded somewhere with iframe.

In my init() function I have this code for keyboard:

```
Keyboard k = PlayN.keyboard();

k.setListener(new Listener() {

    @Override
    public void onKeyUp(Event event) {
}

    @Override
    public void onKeyDown(Event event) {
        /* long long code was here */
    }

   @Override
   public void onKeyTyped(TypedEvent event) {
   }
});
```

This works well, but not with iframe. It simply doesn't have the focus or something.

I found a workaround for this: quickly press F5 and quickly ckick the iframe few times *before* it is loaded. But I want something to do it automatically.

Examples: [with iframe](http://golodmit.appspot.com/playsnake.html) (this have input problems), [no iframe](http://golodmit.appspot.com/game.html) (this works well).

Comment: Why is this relevant to app-engine?

Comment: Totally not related, the app is running on app-engine, but the problem is only about the code, not the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this issue as well. I believe the fix that worked for me was adding the following to the main .html file:

```
<script src="mygamesource.nocache.js"></script> 
<!-- right below your nocache script -->   
<script>  
   function handleMouseDown(evt) {  
     window.focus();   
     evt.preventDefault();  
     evt.stopPropagation();  
     evt.target.style.cursor = 'default';  
   }  
   document.getElementById('body').addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown, false);  
</script>
```

Credit to [this post](http://www.qilineggs.com/2013/06/publishing-html5-game-to-kongregate-and.html) if it works for you.